# Inconsistent handling of Mono.error(OutOfMemoryError)p

Tags: java, project-reactor

I'm trying to understand what happens if you subscribe to a `Mono.error(new OutOfMemoryError("hello world"))` with a couple of variants.

These tests pass for me (using reactor-core 3.4.3):

```java
    @Test
    public void oom() {
        Mono.error(new OutOfMemoryError("hello world")).subscribe();
    }

    @Test
    public void oom_thenReturn() {
        try {
            Mono.error(new OutOfMemoryError("hello world")).thenReturn(123).subscribe();
            fail("Expected OOMError");
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            // expected
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void oom_then_thenReturn() {
        Mono.error(new OutOfMemoryError("hello world")).then().thenReturn(123).subscribe();
    }

    @Test
    public void genericError_thenReturn() {
        Mono.error(new Error("hello world")).thenReturn(123).subscribe();
    }
```

So if you subscribe to `Mono.error(new OutOfMemoryError("hello world")).thenReturn(123)` it throws the exception on the subscribing thread. But if you omit the `thenReturn(123)` call, add an extra `then()` call before it, or use a generic `Error` rather than an `OutOfMemoryError`, no exception is thrown on the subscribing thread. (If you add in a logging `Subscriber`, you see `onSubscribe` and `onError` being called as expected.)

I can see why `OutOfMemoryError` would be treated differently to `Error`, but I can't see why that `thenReturn(123)` call is causing the error to get propagated to the subscribing thread when it isn't otherwise. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with reactor, but could it be that your test finishes before the exception is thrown due to asynchronicity? Maybe you should call `block()` instead of `subscribe()`?

Comment: It's true that all the `block()` calls throw in that case. However, the above behaviour is 100% reproducible (for me, at least) so it doesn't look like a race condition.

Comment: Additionally, if I use `StepVerifier` then I see the same pattern: `StepVerifier.create(Mono.error(new OutOfMemoryError("hello world"))).expectError().verify()` passes, but with `StepVerifier.create(Mono.error(new OutOfMemoryError("hello world")).thenReturn(123)).expectError().verify()` the `verify()` call throws `OutOfMemoryError`. (As I understand it, `StepVerifier` is intended to take race conditions out of the picture.)

Answer (score 1):

`OutOfMemoryError` is considered an unrecoverable exception in Reactor. It probably throws it instead of turning it into an appropriate `onError` signal.

Project Reactor [reference](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/snapshot/reference/#_handling_exceptions_in_operators_or_functions):

> Reactor, however, defines a set of exceptions (such as
> **OutOfMemoryError**) that are always deemed to be fatal. See the
> Exceptions.throwIfFatal method. These errors mean that Reactor cannot
> keep operating and are thrown rather than propagated.

Comment: But why do `Mono.error(new OutOfMemoryError("hello world"))` and `Mono.error(new OutOfMemoryError("hello world")).thenReturn(123)` behave differently?

Comment: @PeteGillin I guess `Mono.error(new OutOfMemoryError("hello world")).thenReturn(123)` fails because it continues operating. I've updated my answer including the corresponding reference.

Comment: Ah, I guess that makes sense, I think we're getting somewhere. Thank you!

Comment: But can you explain why `Mono.error(new OutOfMemoryError("hello world")).then().thenReturn(123)` behaves like `Mono.error(new OutOfMemoryError("hello world"))` rather than like `Mono.error(new OutOfMemoryError("hello world")).thenReturn(123)`? The `then()` call propagates errors so I don't see why that doesn't count as 'keeps operating'.

Comment: @PeteGillin It seems normal to me, because `then()` does exactly what we need: propagates the error signal. The important thing to know is that `OutOfMemoryError` is a fatal error and might cause unpredictable behavior.